# Why does firefox try to accept connections?

Tags: firefox, zonealarm

I have zone alarm and it is telling me that firefox wants to accept connections. Why would it want to do this? It may be a plugin, but I can't think of anything that would require that. Not that it would work through my firewall.

Stopping this dosn't seem to stop anything working, which makes me even more curious.

Comment: Does it happen when you're on a particular site?

Comment: What port is it trying to open?  Does it happen in safe mode?

Answer (score 2):

It might be an add-on you're using. Make sure you don't have any exception for Firefox, then try disabling all add-ons, and enable one by one to see if something triggers your firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox supports [Web Push notifications](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/push-notifications-firefox).

This listens for notifications on a [random UDP port](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=908098).

Comment: This most likely is not the solution to the question in its original context, as I don't think web push existed back in 2009. However, users browsing this question today and in the future may find this information useful.